# how to define ECK form url

Tags: hooks, uri, entities

I am using ECK  
I create one form through  entity->bundle->feedbackform->managedfield  
my form is created, but how to get form path,  
current path is of my feedback form is:-  
admin/structure/entity-type/feedbackform/feedbackform/add  
but this path is not for anonymous user. i want to show my form to anonymous user with some simple path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a module called `'helloworld'`, and entity type called `'vechile'` and a bundle called `'car'`.Here is some code that should do the trick.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */  
function helloworld_menu(){
$items['feedbackform'] = array(
'page callback' => 'example_my_eck_form_page',
'access arguments' => array('Access feedback form'),// permission
'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
return $items;
}

function example_my_eck_form_page(){
   module_load_include('inc', 'eck', 'eck.entity');  
   $bundle_name='car';
   return eck__entity__add('vechile', $bundle_name);   
}


function helloworld_permission() {
   return array(
    'Access feedback form' => array(
      'title' => t('Access feedback form'),
    )
  );
}
```

Access feedback form is a custom permission so you still would have to give that permission to the  users from admin to be able to access the path.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this with ECK, but I believe that the behaviour should be the same as with any other form. You would simply need to:

- Register a menu callback in a custom module for the "simple path", accessible to anonymous user role (see [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7))
- The `'page callback'` can either be

  - a custom function `'example_my_eck_form_page'`, where you `return drupal_get_form('eck_name_of_your_form');`
  - or `'drupal_get_form'` and pass the form name in `'page arguments'` array.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module for that: https://www.drupal.org/project/eck_pm

Alternatively you could use `hook_entity_info_alter` like so:

```
function MYMODULE_entity_info_alter(&$info) {
  if (isset($info['ENTITY']['bundles']['BUNDLE'])) {
    $info['ENTITY']['bundles']['BUNDLE']['crud']['add']['path'] = 'my/public/path';
  }
}
```